# farmers pen part a part b

Tags: calculus

A) A rectangular pen is built with one side against a barn, 200 meters of fencing are used for the other three sides of the pen. What dimensions maximize the area of the pen?

B) A rancher plans to make four identical and adjacent rectangular pens against a barn, each with an area of $100\space \text{m}^2$. What are the dimensions of each pen that minimize the amount of fence to be used?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: I drew a picture of a barn the fence with three sides I labeled two sides x and one side y, 2x+y=200. I'm a bit stuck I know I have to use application of a derivative, I'm familiar with a similar problem but this is a 3 sided fence.

Comment: Keep in mind that $A=xy$ still and we can express $y$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

> A) Let the fence form a the $3$ sides of a rectangle; with the side of the barn being the $4^{th}$ side. Also let $x$ be the width of the rectangle and $y$ be its length. Clearly $2x+y=200 ....(1),  \space \text{and the area enclosed (A) is given by:}\space A=xy....(2)$
>
> Replacing $y$ in (2) by the expression in (1):
>    $$\begin{align}
> A=xy=x(200-2x)= &200x-2x^2 \\
> \frac{dA}{dx}=200-4x \\
> \end{align}$$
>   To maximize the area, $\frac{dA}{dx}=0$ which is equivalent to $x=50 ; y=100$

---

> B) Same situation here, except 
>   $A=4xy=400$
>   $$\begin{align}
> L=\text{total length of fence needed}&=5x+4y \\
> \\
> &= 5x+\frac{400}{x} \\
> \frac{dL}{dx}=5-\frac{400}{x^2}\\
> \end{align}$$
>   To minimize L, $\frac{dL}{dx}=0; \space \text{which is equivalent to} \space x=\sqrt{80}=4\sqrt{5} \approx 8.94; \text{and} \space y=5\sqrt{5} \approx 11.18  $

Answer (score 0):

The question is not uniquely solvable because we don't know the barn's dimensions.

Comment: That's not true. @K.Rmth gives the correct solution. The trick is putting your $y$ lengths in terms of the given perimeter and $x$, then finding critical points.

Comment: That is, under the assumption that the barn is as large as necessary for the maximized area, which _is_ typically assumed for these problems. That this should be part of the question statement is certainly debatable.

Comment: So the farmer's barn in 100 meters long, maybe even longer? Lucky him!  Btw: from $A=x(200-2x)$ you conclude immediately $x=50$. That's the “trick.”  No calculus needed.

Comment: Indeed it isn't necessary, but if you take a look at the other question OP has asked and the fact that both are tagged as calculus and ask essentially about finding critical points, it's pretty obvious that OP is a calc I student looking for help with how to solve basic maximization/minimization problems using calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives are not needed for this problem.

The length restriction:$$2x+y=200$$The area restriction:$$A=x\cdot y$$Combining:$$2x+\frac{A}{x}=200$$ $$2x^2-200x+A=0$$The discriminant of this quadratic is:$$D=(-200)^2-8A$$Now, what is the maximum value of A that still results in a real solution?

The same procedure will solve Part B, with the appropriate area and length expressions, and considering the **minimum** $L$ that permits a real solution.

***Edit to address comment***;

For part B

The length restriction:$$5x+4y=L$$The area restriction:$$100=x\cdot y$$Combining (and multiplying through by $x$):$$5x+\frac{4\cdot 100}{x}=L$$ $$5x^2-Lx+400=0$$The discriminant of this quadratic is:$$D=(L)^2-4\cdot 5\cdot 400$$Now, what is the minimum value of L that still results in a real solution?

Comment: It's not the same procedure.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe:  Looks very similar... I did a lot of cut-and-paste anyway...

Answer (score 0):

A) Using [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),

$$
\frac{(2x+y)^2}{4} \ge 2x \cdot y,\  \text{with equality in case} \ 2x = y
$$

Plug in $2x +y = 200$, maximum area is $\frac{200^2}{8}$.

B) Similarly,
$$
\frac{5x+4y}{2}\ge \sqrt{5x \cdot 4y},\  \text{with equality in case} \ 5x = 4y
$$

Plug in $x\cdot y = 100$, minimal length is $\sqrt{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 100}$