# A person has 20 M of fencing to build a chicken run for their chickens.

Tags: derivatives, quadratics

A person has 20 M of fencing to build a chicken run for their chickens. The side of their barn is also a side of their chicken run. What is the largest area the chicken run can be if it must be rectangular?

How to solve this question?

I literally have no clue on how to solve this question. I have tried to make an equation like 2y+x=20 but it doesn't get me anywhere.

I thank you in advance for helping me

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/556154/362967) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2819096/362967)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
Leaving out one side of barn

$$ 2 B +L = 20 $$

Maximize  $$ A = L * B$$

After plugging in from first equation to eliminate L,

$$ A= B( 20-2B) $$

Result will be when $ L=10, B=5 ,$ with vanishing derivative w.r.to B for maximum area.